# Mysql: Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql

I load xml to mysql database. But it reports ''**Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query**''  after **600sec**.

Mysql version: mysql-installer-community-5.7.9.0

load code:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
PostTypeId SMALLINT,
AcceptedAnswerId INT,
CreationDate DATETIME,
Score INT NULL,
ViewCount INT NULL,
Body text NULL,
OwnerUserId INT,
LastEditorUserId INT,
LastEditDate DATETIME,
LastActivityDate DATETIME,
Title varchar(256),
Tags VARCHAR(256),
AnswerCount INT,
CommentCount INT,
FavoriteCount INT,
CommunityOwnedDate DATETIME,
ParentId INT
```

);

```
load xml infile 'E:/Input/Posts.xml'
into table posts
rows identified by '<row>';
```

I have modifed the file ''**my.ini**'' with following parameters:

```
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
interactive_timeout = 2880000000
connect_timeout = 2880000000
net_write_timeout = 2880000000
wait_timeout = 2880000000
net_read_timeout = 2880000000
```

I didnot find any solution about the Error. 
Anybody can help me fix the bug?

Comment: Posts.xml is very big, 36GB. I get the error when Duration/Fetch is 600sec.

Comment: See how it makes sense to post details about the file. The processing might just take too long to complete within the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the bug.

Edit->Preferences->MySQL Session. Set bigger number of time out.

Comment: What Edit->Preferences? You mean MySQL Workbench? Because you did not say this anywhere.